# Actionscript 3 - Call to a possibly undefined method Round through a reference with static type Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Okay, It seems like I fixed the problem below by turning everything into a public static. But how about the Math functions? It is gicing me a `Error:Call to a possibly undefined method Round through a reference with static type Class`

> I am new to AS3. This is just my 2nd day of coding.. but there seems
>   to be something that I can't understand why it's happening.
>
> ```
>       private var baseExp:int = 10;
>       private var offset:int = 32;
>       private var expCurve:Number = 1.036486;
>       //------------------------
>       private var nextExp:Number = Math.Round(Math.Pow((base_stats[0] * (baseExp / expCurve)), expCurve * (1 + (base_stats[0] / (offset * 5)))));
>       private var _nextExp:Number = nextExp;
>       private var currentExp:int = 0;
>       /*
>        * Check Exp if player can LEVEL UP
>        */
>       public static function CheckExp():void {
>           if (currentExp >= nextExp) {
>               base_stats[0] += 1;
>               //Add Stat Increments here
>               currentExp -= nextExp;
>               for (var i:int = 1; i < base_stats.length; i++) {
>                   trace(base_stats[i]);
>               }
>           }
>           if (nextExp != _nextExp) {
>               RefreshRequiredExp();
>               _nextExp = nextExp;
>           }
>       }
>
> I declared nextExp, _nextExp and currentExp as private... but when I call them in the static function CheckExp, it throws the `Access of
> ```
>
> Undefined Property nextExp` etc. etc.
>
> ```
> And also an `Error: Call to a possibly undefined method Pow through a reference with static type Class.` in the Math functions.
>
> Is there something wrong I'm doing?
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the Math problems by changing `Math.Round` to `Math.round`. same with the others. also the private vars was set to private static var to match the functions. Okayyyy it's fixed.

Wow, I didn't know I can fix this myself.
This is really ridiculous, I feel like I'm just talking to myself.

Comment: I understand. I usually can only find solutions MYSELF if I first ask the entire world for help! Go figure.

Comment: It actually took about an hour trying to figure it out without asking for help. But then after posting this up, I solved it in a matter of minutes. Amazing stuffs.

Comment: @Don It's called "talking to Bob", where "Bob" is a silent person to who you speak about your problem, and stop halfway finally realizing the solution. You can try this technique in case of any troubles I think. It's also said "a good question is already half the answer", so if you ask a question properly, you might be hinted for an answer by your own words.

Comment: By the way, you can accept your own answer just for the others not to waste efforts helping you when that help is no longer needed.